# What's the lowest (private) system-level API in iOS that handles app launching?

Tags: ios, ios10, jailbreak

My goal is to basically, using private APIs, block any app from launching. In other words I'm trying to identify the system "launch" function of Springboard, or Backboard.

So far I've investigated SBUIController, SBApplication and Springboard-Class to no avail. Within them I've identified functions that control launching the app from the home screen, or activating it programmatically. However I haven't been able to locate a "universal" function that handles launching an app from anywhere (Siri, Control Center, Notification Center, App Switcher...)

I'm not even sure such a function exists, hence why I'm asking after hours of reading header files.

PS: The function should work on iOS 10, however any leads from previous versions are welcomed!

Comment: are you still looking to solve this question?

Comment: Yep @Nate I am s interested in finding an answer.